# Is a multicategorical multilevel mediation even possible?

Tags: lme4-nlme, mediation, lm

I've tried to model a multicategorical multilevel mediation by using the logic of [Hayes et al., 2014](https://quantpsy.org/pubs/hayes_preacher_2014.pdf) on multicategorical mediation and an implementation of a [multilevel mediation](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-perform-mediation-with-multilevel-data-method-2/).

Here's a MWE:

```
library(reshape2)
library(lme4)
# Number of subjects
n_subjects <- 30

# Number of conditions
n_conditions <- 4

# Levels of conditions
conditions <- factor(rep(1:n_conditions, times = n_subjects))


# Generate random data for mediator variable M with subject and condition effects
M <- rnorm(n_subjects * n_conditions, mean = rep(1:n_conditions, each = n_subjects), sd = 0.5)

# Generate random data for outcome variable Y with subject and condition effects
Y <- rnorm(n_subjects * n_conditions, mean = rep(1:n_conditions, each = n_subjects), sd = 1)

# Create a data frame
DF <- data.frame(ID = rep(1:n_subjects, each = n_conditions),
                   X = as.factor(conditions),
                   M = M,
                   Y = Y)
```

If I then stack the dataset and perform a lmer to obtain coefficients for indirect effects, I get a rank-deficient model where 1 columns is dropped:

```
#stack dataset
stacked_def <- melt(DF, id.vars = c("fid", "ID", "Y", "X","M"),
                measure.vars = c("Y", "M"), value.name = "Z")
stacked_def <- within(stacked_def, {
  Sy <- as.integer(variable == "Y")
  Sm <- as.integer(variable == "M")
})

#LMM
mm = lme4::lmer(Z ~ 0 + Sm + Sy + Sm:X+ Sy:X+ Sy:M + (0 + Sm + Sy | ID), data = stacked_def)
#Warning: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
mm.matrix = getME(mm, "X")
```

So my question: Is it even possible to include a categorical variable and its interaction with the indicator variables (`Sm` and `Sy`)  into such a parameterization of a linear (mixed) model (without getting the rank-deficient warning)?

---

Actually, I want to even code a custom contrast on X and then perform the LMM:

```
custom_contrasts <- matrix(c(-1, -1, 1, 
                             -1, 1, -1,
                             1, -1, -1,  
                             1, 1, 1),   
                           nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
contrasts(stacked_def$X) <- custom_contrasts

#LMM
mm_cont = lme4::lmer(Z ~ 0 + Sm + Sy + Sm:X+ Sy:X+ Sy:M + (0 + Sm + Sy | ID), data = stacked_def)
#Warning: fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient
mm_cont.matrix = getME(mm_cont, "X")
```

This however, only codes the custom contrast for the Sy:X2 to Sy:X4 columns and not for the Sm:X-columns. Any ideas?